# How can I see https requests from a .NET library - without Fiddler?

Tags: .net, encryption, https, azure-devops, fiddler

I have a .NET application which uses a library that makes some HTTPS calls (background below). The application worked fine, and then one day the library started timing out for no explainable reason - innermost exception says `The HTTP request timed out after 00:05:00`. Nothing changed in my application, or the server AFAIK.

I tried to look at the requests using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but weirdly with Fiddler my application works fine!

**Question:** How can I track the requests made by the library?

I tried capturing with [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), but then I only get opaque `application data`. It's possibly to decrypt SSL, but only if:

- I have the client key. I understand you can get FireFox/Chrose to log session keys ([instruction](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/1088/step-by-step-ssl-decrypt-with-wireshark/)) - but I don't have that option for my .NET library.
- I have the server certificate's private key ([instructions](https://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/)) - but I don't have that.

I also tried a different computer connected to a very different network - same issue.

## Background

My app uses [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/) version `16.136.1-preview` (tried other versions as well) to query a git repo hosted in VSTS.

Comment: The two ways you've listed, or variations on them, are pretty much the only options for inspecting the raw traffic. I'm not very familiar with .NET but maybe there is an option to turn on logging of HTTP requests.

Comment: Bear in mind that there's nothing *stopping* someone from working with Sockets directly for all of their DNS querying and HTTPS work (I wouldn't *suggest* anyone do this, but still, if you have a couple of years with nothing better to do...). Since it's HTTPS you won't get much by inspecting it on the wire, so you pretty well have to do interception on the client and that's commonly via a proxy such as Fiddler.

Comment: You shouldn't need any reverse engineering as the API are well documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1 : that library is just a wrapper

Comment: @guilio: I'm aware of VSTS REST APIs, and indeed see the calls to them when running with Fiddler. However, the exact same calls timeout when running directly - which is what I'm trying to debug here.

Comment: @Jonathan Just try [.NET Tracker](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/.NET-Tracker) to check if that helps for you.

Comment: I've had a very similar issue: I wrote a console application targeting .NET Core 2.1 and I experienced exceptions thrown by ``HttpClient`` (the top of the stack trace read "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host").
I couldn't manage to reproduce it with Fiddler.
My workaround was to retarget my application to .NET 4.6 and the problem was automagically solved.
Very weird.

Comment: @Leonardo: I get `The HTTP request timed out after 00:05:00` (edited question to add). I originally targeted .NET 4.5.2, now tried 4.6.2 and 4.7 - same issue.